# Blazor eventcallback only executes once when eventcallback is set

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

In bazor wasm I am making a paginator component, to add pagination to a table component. The paginator component takes an event callback (`PageChanged`) which is executed when the user changes the page.

Here is the view

```
<div id="paginator-container">
<div id="paginator-controls">
    <button type="button"
            class="btn btn-action"
            @onclick="@this.GoToFirstPage"
            disabled="@this.IsFirstPage">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="button"
            class="btn btn-action"
            @onclick="@this.GoToPreviousPage"
            disabled="@this.IsFirstPage">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
    </button>
    <span>
        page @this.CurrentPage of @this.PageCount
    </span>
    <button class="btn btn-action"
            @onclick="@this.GoToNextPage"
            disabled="@this.IsLastPage">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-action"
            @onclick="@this.GoToLastPage"
            disabled="@this.IsLastPage">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

And the associated code

```
public partial class Paginator
{
    [Parameter]
    public int Lenght { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<InnosysPaginatorContext> PageChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int PageSize { get; set; } = 50;

    private int CurrentPage { get; set; }

    private int PageCount { get; set; }

    private bool IsFirstPage
        => this.CurrentPage == 1;

    private bool IsLastPage
        => this.CurrentPage == this.PageCount;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        this.SetPageCount();

        this.CurrentPage = 1;

        base.OnParametersSet();
    }

    private void SetPageCount()
    {
        decimal pageCount = (decimal)this.Lenght / this.PageSize;

        if (pageCount != Math.Floor(pageCount))
        {
            pageCount = Math.Floor(pageCount + 1);
        }

        this.PageCount = (int)pageCount;
    }

    private async Task GoToFirstPage()
        => await this.GoToPage(1);

    private async Task GoToPreviousPage()
        => await this.GoToPage(this.CurrentPage - 1);

    private async Task GoToNextPage()
        => await this.GoToPage(this.CurrentPage + 1);

    private async Task GoToLastPage()
        => await this.GoToPage(this.PageCount);

    private Task GoToPage(int pageIndex)
    {
        this.CurrentPage = Math.Clamp(pageIndex, 1, this.PageCount);

        return this.ExecutePageChangedEvent();
    }

    private async Task ExecutePageChangedEvent()
        => await this.PageChanged.InvokeAsync(new InnosysPaginatorContext
        {
            CurrentPage = this.CurrentPage,
            PageSize = this.PageSize
        });
}
```

When I use the paginator without setting `PageChanged`, like this:

```
<Paginator Lenght="300" />
```

I can move through the pages just fine.

However, if I set the callback, like this

```
<Paginator Lenght="300"
       PageChanged="@this.OnPageChangedTest" />

<p>Page: @pageIndex</p>

<p>page size: @pageSize</p>

@code{

    int pageIndex = 1;

    int pageSize = 50;

    void OnPageChangedTest(InnosysPaginatorContext innosysPaginatorContext)
    {
        pageIndex = innosysPaginatorContext.CurrentPage;

        pageSize = innosysPaginatorContext.PageSize;
    }

}
```

The buttons only work once and I can only get to page 2. Subsequent clicks on the buttons for the next page execute the callback, but the `CurrentPage` of the paginator is stuck on page 2.
Why does this happen?

Comment: @BrianParker, thank you. I modified the code to paste it here and forgot to fix that in between pasting.

Comment: quick hint: in C# the `this` object is implied, unlike in JS. You don't need to specify it (unless trying to differentiate between a local method-scoped variable and a class value)

Comment: See my new answer:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue must be here:

```
this.CurrentPage = 1;
```

is executed whenever OnParametersSet is executed; actually, you don't need to set CurrentPage to 1. And if you need to do it only once, you should do it in the OnInitialized(Async) pair

```
 protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        this.SetPageCount();

      //  this.CurrentPage = 1;

        base.OnParametersSet();
    }
```